# Prove or Disprove If $T : R^n \rightarrow\ell_2$ is linear, then $T(A)$ is totally bounded in $\ell_2$ when $A ⊆ R^n$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Prove or Disprove, If $ T: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \ell_2 $ is linear, then It preserves total boundedness  $ T(A) $ is totally bounded in $\ell_2$ when $A \subseteq\mathbb R^n$ is bounded.
I think this is not true. am i right?

Comment: Fix that LaTeX hotchpotch in the title!

Comment: This is true. Note that $\overline{A}$ is compact. Why does that help you?

Comment: Do you have counter example of my problem? @ phoemuex